# BeautifulSoup -ing a website with login and site search engine

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape International Maritime Organization's data (https://gisis.imo.org/Public/PAR/Search.aspx) on shipping vessel attacks between the dates ("is between" in the site's search engine) 2002-01-01, 2005-12-31.

[image: Fill in the dates and click add]

I've used bs4 and requests modules in python previously to scrape financial data from yahoo, and weather data from wunderground, but this site requires a login and password (under the "public" account type).  Furthermore, as I said the data requires a search / filter before I can access the html on the page:

[image]

Once I click on a row here, it expands to the image below. (Before anyone asks why I don't just download the dataset and pull from there: the DL is for some reason filtered, and not all the columns are given out (for example, the IMO number).

[image]

*ULTIMATELY THE DATA I AM TRYING TO PULL IS FROM THIS PAGE*, and I need (item, css path):

- position of incident

  ```
  #ctl00_bodyPlaceHolder_ctl00_pnlDetail > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > span
  ```
- date

  ```
  #ctl00_bodyPlaceHolder_ctl00_pnlDetail > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td.content > span
  ```
- ship name

  ```
  #ctl00_bodyPlaceHolder_ctl00_pnlDetail > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > span
  ```

Needless to say this seems like a daunting task.  Any recommendations?

**Here is the OLD code I've been using to scrape the weather data (haven't changed anything yet because I don't know where to start in terms of the login/filter process:**
http://pythonfiddle.com/get-wx-data

Comment: @salmanwahed edited and added the pyfiddle.  I haven't changed it from my previous scraper yet because I honestly don't even know where to start.  I can point the scraper at the css elements, but how do I get the site to go through the search/filter process?

Comment: Hi d8aninja, I am trying to do the same, did you manage to scrape this website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` alone isn't going to be enough. You'll want to look into `mechanize`: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

The nice thing about `mechanize` is that it maintains state from page to page, unlike `requests`. (You probably could do it with just `requests`, but I'm not quite that clever.) [Here's](http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/pythons-mechanize-login-like-a-user/) an example of a simple login interaction.

This would be awesome, if the IMO site were that easy. Instead, it's ASP-based, and that means it's relatively irritating to scrape. Some of the details will vary from site to site, so I'll suggest two things in particular: looking at the Network tab of [your browser's developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-resource-details) and reading [this ScraperWiki post](https://blog.scraperwiki.com/2011/11/how-to-get-along-with-an-asp-webpage/) on dealing with ASP sites.

Best of luck!

Comment: much thanks. I'm still working on editing the script I have been using (OP) but this is good info.